# invalid register for .seh_savexmm in Cygwin

Tags: gcc, assembly, cygwin, avx512

$ make
i have worked with cygwin but got compile error.
I am not sure what is invalid register for .seh_savexmm 
please help me.
I searched this problem on google but not find 
there are many problems but not soultion.
Please help me.

```
perl ./generate-functions.pl -file operationMetadata.csv
g++ -std=c++14 -O3 -Wall -g -mavx512vl -mavx512f -mavx512pf -mavx512er -mavx512cd -fno-common -c int-test.c -o int-test.o
g++ -std=c++14 -O3 -Wall -g -mavx512vl -mavx512f -mavx512pf -mavx512er -mavx512cd -fno-common -c generated-functions.c -o generated-functions.o
/tmp/cczD9mlv.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/cczD9mlv.s:39: Error: invalid register for .seh_savexmm
/tmp/cczD9mlv.s:41: Error: invalid register for .seh_savexmm
/tmp/cczD9mlv.s:43: Error: invalid register for .seh_savexmm
/tmp/cczD9mlv.s:45: Error: invalid register for .seh_savexmm
/tmp/cczD9mlv.s:47: Error: invalid register for .seh_savexmm
/tmp/cczD9mlv.s:49: Error: invalid register for .seh_savexmm
/tmp/cczD9mlv.s:51: Error: invalid register for .seh_savexmm
/tmp/cczD9mlv.s:53: Error: invalid register for .seh_savexmm
/tmp/cczD9mlv.s:55: Error: invalid register for .seh_savexmm
/tmp/cczD9mlv.s:57: Error: invalid register for .seh_savexmm
/tmp/cczD9mlv.s:59: Error: invalid register for .seh_savexmm
/tmp/cczD9mlv.s:61: Error: invalid register for .seh_savexmm
/tmp/cczD9mlv.s:63: Error: invalid register for .seh_savexmm
/tmp/cczD9mlv.s:65: Error: invalid register for .seh_savexmm
/tmp/cczD9mlv.s:67: Error: invalid register for .seh_savexmm
/tmp/cczD9mlv.s:69: Error: invalid register for .seh_savexmm
```

Comment: What version of g++ are you using. Might be a bug with Cygwin's GCC.

Comment: i used version 5.4

Comment: it worked good in my ubuntu. now i want to compile in cygwin

Comment: If you don't need Windows Structured Exception support you can try using the `-fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables` option. This may however just mask some other underlying problem. Also some of the AVX512 instruction sets you've enabled are only supported on the Intel Xeon Phi x200, unless you're running Windows on one of those your code may not work.

Comment: Thanks Ross Ridge. I solved   i added -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables it solved underlying problem. Thanks :):):)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ross Ridge is Right. I solved that only adding -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables. thanks Ross.

Comment: this fixed it for me with libvpx mingw64 as well

Comment: I get the same error with G++ 7.4.0 Cygwin when compiling with option -mavx512vl.

-fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables solves it.

Has this bug been fixed? Has anybody reported it as a bug?

Comment: The bug has not been fixed yet. See https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=65782

Comment: @a-fog has this become better? I read in the bug you linked that it as marked as resolved in February 2020 in the GCC 8 branch. I also can't reproduce the crashes of https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54412 with GCC 10.2.0 on MinGW but maybe I'm dong something wrong...

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered this bug recently. I found another approach for this: use `-ffixed-reg` option to disable use of xmm16..31 registers. You have to specify it for each register separately. Here is full list of options which you have to use:

```
-ffixed-xmm16 -ffixed-xmm17 -ffixed-xmm18 -ffixed-xmm19
-ffixed-xmm20 -ffixed-xmm21 -ffixed-xmm22 -ffixed-xmm23
-ffixed-xmm24 -ffixed-xmm25 -ffixed-xmm26 -ffixed-xmm27
-ffixed-xmm28 -ffixed-xmm29 -ffixed-xmm30 -ffixed-xmm31
```

After doing so compiler will not be able to use them, so it will have to store some data on stack instead of registers. This most probably will result in a slower code.

You can also try to use `-flto` flag, some people reported that it also helps. In my case it only reduced number of errors, so check if it will work for you.

Comment: Does gcc not know that xmm16..31 are call-clobbered on Windows x64?  Only xmm6..15 are call-preserved (and only the xmm part, not the ymm or zmm upper lanes). 
 Presumably SEH can only encode unwind info for xmm0..15.  [Is xmm8 register value preserved across calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53733767)

Comment: If LTO helps, it's probably only by enabling more inlining.  I would have assumed that leaf functions would still need SEH unwind info, but possibly with more inlining gcc uses different registers?  Anyway, `-ffixed-reg` seems like a nasty workaround until the underlying gcc bug is fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I will add it to gcc bug report (https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=65782). I hope that gcc people will finally fix it.

Comment: It looks that LTO helps in other way. When I enabled it, I got .s file for problematic .cpp file with size ~14.8MB, and myapp.exe.ltrans0.s with size ~480KB. Errors were reported for latter one only. So looks that this file has dead code eliminated. If errors were in that dead code, they will also will go away. Plus inlining mentioned by you may also help here.

Comment: Hmm, `-flto` isn't quite the same as `-fwhole-program`, but maybe when linking an executable (instead of a DLL) it can still remove stand-alone definitions for some functions.  The `.s` files will always be huge because LTO emits the GIMPLE internal representation (in a special section) as well as x86 asm, and the link-time optimizer (linker plugin) only reads the GIMPLE to inline/optimize based on that.  But the `.s` still has to assemble into a valid `.o`, and it sounds like the problem was at assemble time, not link time.