# Opencv 3.4.1 error invalid register for .seh_savexmm

Tags: opencv

I am getting following error when I run mingw32-make

D:\MAS\AppData\Local\Temp\ccksf6tI.s: Assembler messages:
D:\MAS\AppData\Local\Temp\ccksf6tI.s:21573: Error: invalid register for .seh_savexmm
D:\MAS\AppData\Local\Temp\ccksf6tI.s:21575: Error: invalid register for .seh_savexmm
D:\MAS\AppData\Local\Temp\ccksf6tI.s:21577: Error: invalid register for .seh_savexmm
D:\MAS\AppData\Local\Temp\ccksf6tI.s:21579: Error: invalid register for .seh_savexmm
D:\MAS\AppData\Local\Temp\ccksf6tI.s:21581: Error: invalid register for .seh_savexmm
D:\MAS\AppData\Local\Temp\ccksf6tI.s:21583: Error: invalid register for .seh_savexmm
D:\MAS\AppData\Local\Temp\ccksf6tI.s:21585: Error: invalid register for .seh_savexmm
D:\MAS\AppData\Local\Temp\ccksf6tI.s:21587: Error: invalid register for .seh_savexmm
D:\MAS\AppData\Local\Temp\ccksf6tI.s:21589: Error: invalid register for .seh_savexmm
D:\MAS\AppData\Local\Temp\ccksf6tI.s:21591: Error: invalid register for .seh_savexmm
D:\MAS\AppData\Local\Temp\ccksf6tI.s:21593: Error: invalid register for .seh_savexmm
D:\MAS\AppData\Local\Temp\ccksf6tI.s:21595: Error: invalid register for .seh_savexmm
D:\MAS\AppData\Local\Temp\ccksf6tI.s:21597: Error: invalid register for .seh_savexmm
D:\MAS\AppData\Local\Temp\ccksf6tI.s:21599: Error: invalid register for .seh_savexmm
mingw32-make[2]: *** [modules\dnn\CMakeFiles\opencv_dnn.dir\build.make:1016: modules/dnn/CMakeFiles/opencv_dnn.dir/layers/layers_common.avx512_skx.cpp.obj] Error 1
mingw32-make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:4083: modules/dnn/CMakeFiles/opencv_dnn.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:162: all] Error 2

I have already tested by passing -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables to cmake3.11
I am running windows 10 ver 1709

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43152633/invalid-register-for-seh-savexmm-in-cygwin

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling Dispatched CPU optimizations by passing the `-DCPU_DISPATCH=` flag to CMake.

Edit: Your compiler doesn't support AVX optimizations. If you're building with CMake, clear the `CPU_DISPATCH` row of anything AVX-related.