# Is xmm8 register value preserved across calls?

Tags: assembly, visual-c++, x86-64, cpu-registers, abi

My Windows program compiled using Visual Studio 2017 does the following:

- calls a routine that has a default argument with value 35.05.
- initializes the Java Virtual Machine through the C interface
- calls the routine again that has the default argument with value 35.05.

In the first call, the default argument gets the correct 35.05. In the second call that value is garbage.

I looked at the generated assembly and during the first call with the default argument 35.05 is copied to `xmm8` from a memory location and it's copied to the stack (it's the 5th parameter) and the call is made:

```
0033d   48 8b 01     mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rcx]
00340   41 b8 14 00 00
00       mov     r8d, 20 // a default argument
00346   f3 44 0f 10 05
00 00 00 00  movss   xmm8, DWORD PTR __real@420c3333 // this is 35.05
0034f   f3 44 0f 11 44
24 28        movss   DWORD PTR [rsp+40], xmm8
00356   48 c7 44 24 20
1e 00 00 00  mov     QWORD PTR [rsp+32], 30 // a default argument
0035f   45 8d 48 05  lea     r9d, QWORD PTR [r8+5]
00363   b2 0f        mov     dl, 15 // a default argument
00365   ff 90 08 01 00
00       call    QWORD PTR [rax+264]
```

Then the call is made to initialize the JVM.

Then for the next call, `xmm8` is used again to copy the value to the stack:

```
00ce8   48 8b 01     mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rcx]
00ceb   41 b8 14 00 00
00       mov     r8d, 20
00cf1   f3 44 0f 11 44
24 28        movss   DWORD PTR [rsp+40], xmm8
00cf8   48 c7 44 24 20
1e 00 00 00  mov     QWORD PTR [rsp+32], 30
00d01   45 8d 48 05  lea     r9d, QWORD PTR [r8+5]
00d05   b2 0f        mov     dl, 15
00d07   ff 90 08 01 00
00       call    QWORD PTR [rax+264]
```

But now, `xmm8` has been overwritten.

If I take out the call to initialize the JVM, then the value is preserved.

The question is, who's in the wrong here? JVM is not preserving the value or Microsoft compiler was in the wrong to assume `xmm8` value will be preserved.

Comment: [`xmm8` must be preserved by callee](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/register-usage) so the JVM is at fault if it really destroys `xmm8`.

Comment: Thank you. That document didn't show up in all my Googling :(

Comment: Which JVM is this?  Oracle?  If it accepts args in the registers that Windows x64 uses, but clobbers registers it shouldn't, that sounds broken.  Custom calling conventions are possible, but make interacting with compiled C / C++ impossible without asm wrappers.  It sounds like this might be an unintentional calling-convention difference, i.e. a bug in the JVM.

Comment: @PeterCordes yes, Oracle and they have accepted and fixed the [bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8067744). I should've mentioned I was using Java 1.8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Windows x64 calling convention summarized from [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/register-usage).

`RCX`, `RDX`, `R8`, and `R9` are used as input integer parameters. `XMM0L`, `XMM1L`, `XMM2L`, and `XMM3L` are input floating-point parameters. `RAX`, `R10`, `R11`, `XMM4`, and `XMM5` are volatile. All others including `XMM8` are non-volatile.

> Note that the "Caller/Callee Saved Registers" sub-page is a bit misleading right now because it doesn't include the SSE registers.

**UPDATE:** Any additional registers for newer instruction sets are volatile by default. This includes the upper parts of `YMM0-15` and `ZMM0-15` as well as `?MM16-31` if present.

Comment: Worth mentioning that the high lanes of ymm6..15 and zmm6..31 are call-clobbered.  Only strictly xmm6..15 (the low 128 bits) are call-preserved.  With AVX512VL, even xmm16..31 can be clobbered, I think.

Comment: I'm not sure how about those extra registers, but they probably are volatile. I'll see if I can track someone down...

Comment: Anything that didn't exist when the ABI was created is volatile because doing otherwise is a BackCompat issue.